# Ошибка MSB4184 при загрузке проекта .net core

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core

Здравствуйте.

При загрузке проекта netcore в vs2015 возникает ошибка:

```
Error MSB4184   The expression "Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Setup\EDev@StanDir" cannot be evaluated.
[C:\Users\Arina Korshunova\Projects\micro\Xrm.Micro\Tests\Test.RoomsService\Test.RoomsService.xproj]
```

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

.net core установлен

[image: Версия установленного dotnet]

Может кто-то сталкивался с таким или знает как это лечится?

Comment: Ну вот, хотел добавить [ссылку](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/454), а ты там уже отписалась. У тебя только 2015 студия установлена? или 2017 тоже?

Comment: Добавь содержимое файла проекта

Comment: Возможно [связанный вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3297947/2881286)